# React - Data loaded able to console log but not showing up in DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I checked the log, and the data in state `Classs` and `Classes` is good
but when I entered the page, `{ renderCards }` didn't show up.

The funny thing is this, when I fix the code and save it, my local server is reloaded and then `{ renderCards }` shows up! why?

```html
function ClassDetailPage(props) {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();        
    const classId = props.match.params.classId
    const [Classs, setClasss] = useState({})
    const [Classes, setClasses] = useState([])
    console.log(Classs.desc_image);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(videoclasslist())
        .then((res) => {
            const class_list = res.payload
            console.log(class_list,'123');
            setClasses(class_list)
        })
    }, [dispatch])

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(videoclassdetail(classId))
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.payload);
            setClasss(res.payload)            
            console.log(res.payload.content);  
        })
    }, [dispatch])


    


    const renderCards = Classes.map((product, index) => {
        return <a href={'/videoclass/detail/'+ product.id } key={index}>
        
            <Card className="owl-theme Other-Class">
                <Card.Img className="Other-Class-Image" src={API_BASE_URL+product.image}/>  
                <Card.Title className="Other-Class-Title">{product.title}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text className="Other-Class-Trainer">{product.nickname}</Card.Text>
                <Card.Text className="Other-Class-Price">월 {product.price}원 <Badge variant="warning">Free</Badge></Card.Text>            
            </Card>
            
        </a>
    })
    
    return (
        <div>   
        <div className="detail-board">
            <Row>
                <Col className="imagespace" lg={6} xs={12}>
                    <Image className="img-fluid" src={API_BASE_URL + Classs.desc_image}/>
                </Col>
                <Col lg={6} xs={12}>
                    {/* ProductInfo */}
                    <ProductInfo detail={Classs} />
                </Col>                            
            </Row>
        </div>
            <h2> classes</h2>
            <Row className="Other-Classes-Row">
                <OwlCarousel className="Other-Classes" loop items={3} autoplay ={true}>
                    { renderCards }
                </OwlCarousel>
            </Row>
            <br/>
       
        </div>        
    )   
}


export default ClassDetailPage
```

Comment: `renderCards()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you return the whole JSX part inside the `renderCards` map function, not just `<a href={'/videoclass/detail/' + product.id} key={index}>`. Try to wrap everything inside parentheses like this:

```js
const renderCards = Classes.map((product, index) => {
  return (
    <a href={'/videoclass/detail/' + product.id} key={index}>
      <Card className="owl-theme Other-Class">
        <Card.Img
          className="Other-Class-Image"
          src={API_BASE_URL + product.image}
        />
        <Card.Title className="Other-Class-Title">{product.title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text className="Other-Class-Trainer">
          {product.nickname}
        </Card.Text>
        <Card.Text className="Other-Class-Price">
          월 {product.price}원 <Badge variant="warning">Free</Badge>
        </Card.Text>
      </Card>
    </a>
  );
});
```